# JQuery IE8 WinXP compatible version

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have recently been developing a website which relies a large part on the use of JQuery, the target browser is IE8, but I have been developing on a Win7 machine and have only just now realised that there is a difference in compatability between IE8 on WinXP & Win7.

So a lot of stuff is throwing random javascript errors in the JQuery file in IE8 on WinXP, so I would like to know what is the most comptatible version of JQuery for IE8 on WinXP and Win7 if it is possible.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Have you confirmed that these errors are not appearing in other versions of IE? All versions of jQuery should support IE8 just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it's jQuery. Make sure that you don't have compatibility mode enabled on one machine and not on the other.

You can also force compatibility mode off by adding the following tag in your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```